# How to display black chess pieces within normal text with chessfss

Tags: chess

I'm using the package `chessboard` do display chess diagrams, and therefore `chessfss` is used for chess fonts if my understanding is correct.

To display the *white* chess pieces within normal text when writing explanations, I use the commands `\pawn`, `\rook`, `\knight`, `\bishop`, `\queen` and `\king` (see the example below).

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\begin{document}
  White pieces : \pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king\\


  Black pieces : \BlackPawnOnWhite \BlackRookOnWhite \BlackKnightOnWhite
  \BlackBishopOnWhite \BlackQueenOnWhite \BlackKingOnWhite
\end{document}
```

[image: Chess pieces symbols within normal text]

What are the corresponding commands to display the *black* pieces? I have tried commands like `\BlackPawnOnWhite` but as you can see it is not suited to in-text use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There aren't many chessfonts which actually contain black figurine pieces. I only know the berlin family and there you need to change the font shape to access them:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\begin{document}
\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king

\setfigfontfamily{berlin}
\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king 

\fontshape{bl}\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use another chess font you will have to get suitable glyphs first. You could e.g. ask the author of skaknew to add them. I could then create support files.

## Edit

You could get glyphs by taking the font with the board pieces and then create a virtual font which changes the bounding boxes so that they sit better on the line.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Since I have to manually install the chess fonts in Fedora, I'll look further into it when I have some time.

Comment: Where to find the `berlin` font?

Comment: @PaulGaborit: It is in the enpassant package (on CTAN). With miktex you can install it with the package manager, with texlive you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 6):

Since I almost don't understand anything about fonts, I have defined using `adjustbox` new commands which trim, resize and scale the board pieces. It is kind of an ugly workaround, I know...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\pawnB}[1][1.3ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=4.3pt 2.6pt 4.3pt 0pt,width=#1,margin=0.2ex 0ex 0.2ex 0ex}{\BlackPawnOnWhite}%
}%
\newcommand{\rookB}[1][1.58ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=3.2pt 2.2pt 3.2pt 0pt,width=#1,raise=0ex,margin=0.1ex 0ex 0.1ex 0ex}{\BlackRookOnWhite}%
}%
\newcommand{\knightB}[1][1.85ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=2.3pt 2.35pt 2.5pt 0pt,width=#1,raise=-0.03ex,margin=0.14ex 0ex 0.14ex 0ex}{\BlackKnightOnWhite}%
}%
\newcommand{\bishopB}[1][1.79ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=2.3pt 2pt 2.3pt 0pt,width=#1,raise=-0.12ex,margin=0.1ex 0ex 0.1ex 0ex}{\BlackBishopOnWhite}%
}%
\newcommand{\queenB}[1][2.05ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=1.2pt 2.2pt 1.2pt 0pt,width=#1,raise=-0.08ex,margin=0.1ex 0ex 0.1ex 0ex}{\BlackQueenOnWhite}%
}%
\newcommand{\kingB}[1][1.95ex]{%
\adjustbox{Trim=2pt 2pt 2pt 0pt,width=#1,raise=-0.06ex,margin=0.13ex 0ex 0.13ex 0ex}{\BlackKingOnWhite}%
}%

\begin{document}
\pawn  \rook   \knight   \bishop   \queen  \king\\
\pawnB \rookB  \knightB  \bishopB  \queenB \kingB
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with the new commands defined from the board pieces]

Answer (score 6):

The `alpha` font family has black figurines stored within `\fontshape{bl}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessfss}

\begin{document}

\setfigfontfamily{alpha}

\figfont KQRBNp

\fontshape{bl}\figfont KQRBNp

\fontshape{*}\figfont KQRBNp

\end{document}
```

[image: Chess alpha font family figurines in white and black.]

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the piece sizes can be resolved with the following:

```
\usepackage{chessfss}
\setboardfontsize{10pt}
```

Comment: It only changes the size of the pieces, not their positions.