# Display a key/legend beside a chess board diagram

Tags: chess, chessboard

Is it possible to display a key (legend) beside a chess board image in latex? That is, a list of piece names and the corresponding pictorial representation. I am using the latex chessboard package at the moment, but could change if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A solution given by @UlrikeFischer -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150045/197451 -- you could ping the author for further help

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\begin{document}
\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king

\setfigfontfamily{berlin}
\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king 

\fontshape{bl}\pawn \rook \knight \bishop \queen \king
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the authors request for "a list of piece names and the corresponding pictorial representation": could you please also show how to add the "list of names" to the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

The low-level approach of js bibra with the chessfss package can also be applied to the chessboard package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}

\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

\chessboard[setpieces={Ke1,Qd1,Rg1,ra1,rh8,ke8},showmover=false]

% How to show black pieces?
\king ~ King (K)\\
\queen ~ Queen (Q)\\
\rook ~ Rook (R)\\
\bishop ~ Bishop (B)\\
\knight ~ Knight (N)\\
\pawn ~ Pawn (P)

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to draw black pieces though.